# a and p inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a and p elements into div block, but when I open developer tools, it shows that they are not child of div element. What I'm doing wrong? Someone please suggest me the right way to do it right. P.S I'm new to web design.

html and css here:

```
<div id="header">
            <!-- header -->
            <p id="banner-text">Banner Text</p>
        </div>

        <div id="body">
            <!-- body -->
            <div id="testid">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/g/r/green-check-icone-4881-128.png"/>
                    <p>Testing...</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <!-- footer -->
        </div>

#header
{
    width: 980px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #abcdef;
}
#body
{
    width: 980px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #aaabbb;
}
#footer
{
    width: 980px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #abcdef;
}
#banner-text
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: -45px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#testid
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#testid a
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

#testid img
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    top: -70px;
    left: 15px;
}

#testid p
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 8px;
    top: -90px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 0px;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R4anp/

Regards.

Comment: When I open developer tools, it shows that they **are** a child of the div element. I can't reproduce your problem. Is it specific to a browser? Does the problem not appear on the JS Fiddle you created?

Comment: you mean your source on the browser is not showing the a and p inside the div?

Comment: Works fine here.  Dev tools inspection of your JSFiddle shows the your a and p tags are inside the div tag, just as your code says it should be.

Comment: AFAIK when I'm using relative position, it should be relative to DIV element (because they are children of DIV) but instead, it shows different results. Tested with Chrome and Firefox on Linux, but got different results there.

Comment: PS try grabbing the element in firefox, it shows big block, which I can't change.. am I doing everything fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to wrap a block element `<p>` with an inline element `<a>` which is not W3C compliant. Can you wrap your link in your paragraph tag instead?

**Edit:** This is valid in HTML5.

Comment: It is in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) `"The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). This example shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a link"`

Comment: It seems that the OP did not declare the right doctype.

Comment: @Adrift Good point. Answer updated.

Comment: Oh.. instead I should use <p><a href="test></a>Testing</p> ?

Comment: Alright, seems problem was with <p> tag inside <a>. Thank you for information.

Comment: That would make more sense, but as @Terry and @Probocop point out, adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` might make it work in JSFiddle. I wouldn't normally put a paragraph tag inside a link though.

Comment: The fiddle looks fine to me when you declare HTML5 for DTD :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine with a HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using HTML5 by now. I'm learning from HTML4 first.

Comment: HTML5 is an extension of HTML4 of sorts (it's an overgeneralized statement though). It just has a lot of new hooks and features, but all your code written in HTML4 will be valid in HTML5.